# Reaction of phoshorus pentasulfide with ethers

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Why does phosphorous pentasulfide on reaction with ethers give dialkyl sulfides?

I searched for this reaction in my organic chemistry reference books and the internet but couldn't find it.

What is the mechanism of the reaction? I expected the oxygen as nucleophile to attack P atom but am not sure of the steps that follow.

Comment: You searched your reference books and the internet and couldn't find the reaction. How do you know it actually happens? Do you mean an ether (ROR) or some other oxygen functionality such as an amide?

Comment: I found one claim of ether(ethylene gylcol monoalkyl ether) reacting with phosphorus pentasulfide though I am not sure this is what you are looking for. See: https://apps.dtic.mil/docs/citations/AD0673686